# getlines undefined in iostream in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, getline

Here's my code:
For some reason, `getline` is saying undefined. My professor told me that I might be using an older version of C++ but I have no clue how to check it.

I'm using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013. Please save me.

Thanks in advance.

BTW: I don't mind any errors in the code non-relevant to the `getline` please. The code is not complete but I can't test it when `getline` is undefined.

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string concatenatedLines;

    getline(cin, concatenatedLines);

    if (!cin)
    { // C++ can overwrite conversion operator... cin is being converter into a boolean operator. It is FALSE if you attempted to read and there's nothing there.
        return 1;
    }

    // START OF MISSING CODE *-=*-=*-=*-=*-=*-=*-=*-=*-=*-=*-=*-=*-=*-=*-=*-=
    //
    int numberOfLines = 1;
    int stat = 0;
    string line;
    string space = " ";
    while (stat == 0)
    {
        getline(cin, line);
        if (!cin) stat = 1;
        else{
            concatenatedLines = line + space + concatenatedLines;
            numberOfLines++;
        }
    }
    //
    // END OF MISSING CODE *-=*-=*-=*-=*-=*-=*-=*-=*-=*-=*-=*-=*-=*-=*-=*-=

    cout << concatenatedLines << endl;
    //endl = end of the line - declared in the standart library
    cout << concatenatedLines << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Include `string` header.

Answer (score 3):

You also need to include the `<string>` header.